# Slickslider.js loading issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

We are using slick slider for a clients project and it has been working perfectly so far, however I have noticed something, I don't know whether it is a bug or something that I am missing something.

This is my config code for the slider below:

```
$('.alt-options-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    accessibility: true,
    centerMode: true,
    touchMove: true,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: false,
    mobileFirst: true,
    centerPadding: '25px 30px',
    edgeFriction: 0.30,
    accessibility: true,
    arrows: false,
    prevArrow: $('.prev'),
    nextArrow: $('.next'),

    settings: "unslick",
    responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 767,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 2,
                centerMode: false,
                centerPadding: '0px',
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 992,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 5,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                settings: "unslick",
                centerMode: false,
                centerPadding: '0px',
            }
        },
    ]
});
```

This only happens on mobile, but when the slider comes into the screen it stacks like this

[image]

Then after I scroll down to show the whole slider it kind of realises that it is not right and jumps back into place as it should and looks like this

[image]

Comment: add smaller breakpoint for 1 slide only?

Comment: @YOU Breakpoints are not the issue, as it is mobileFirst untill the breakpoint size of a tablet portrait